# How to apply awk command over multiple file to extract row?

Tags: linux, awk

I have two major files

1) Bigfile is of 99 million rows. I have splitted the big into small chunk.
2) File2 having some other information.

```
  Majorfiles information is below :- 

  Bigfile
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  
  A      1     A     T
  A      2     A     T
  A      3     G     C
  A      4     C     G
  A      5     G     T
  A      6     T     A

 File2
 Col1   Col2  Col3      
 A       4    Usefull 
 A       6    NonUsefull
```

Bigfile is split into small chunk so all the small chunk has same information which i have given above for bigfile.

What i want is

file3

```
 Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  
  A      4     C     G
  A      6     T     A
```

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline<"Bigfile")>0) {REC[$2]=$0}} {print REC[$2]}'  <   file2 > file3
```

but because this is huge file with 99 million rows so i am not getting the output. Whereas if I split in 100000 rows i get the output. So i tried splitting the file into smaller chunk using below commands

```
split -l 100000 -d Bigfile.txt smallfile- --additional-suffix=.txt
```

And next i put all the file into loop using below code

```
files=`ls *txt | sed "s|ls *txt||"` 

for i in $files
do
R1=${i}.txt #join
echo `awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline<"$R1")>0) {REC[$2]=$0}} {print REC[$2]}' <   file2 > file_${i}`
done
```

but file_${i} is giving me text file contain only command

"awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline<"$R1")>0) {REC[$2]=$0}} {print REC[$2]}"

No expected output i got.

Comment: Not at all clear, could you please elaborate why you want to run `awk` again if file is already divided into chunks? If you want to divide the huge file then what should be the criteria of it? Kindly elaborate more on it.

Comment: Dividing the file is not my query i used awk for starting 10000 row (on splitted file). Now i have 99 such file so i can not run awk 99 times so i re-run putting everything in loop.

Comment: You need not to run `awk` 99 times you could invoke single `awk` and could read all 99 files for example `awk 'code here..' file[0-9][0-9]`, try it out once.

Comment: 1 thing still not clear by reading those files what is the expected output you need? Please be more clear in your post.

Comment: My file names are smallfile-00.txt smallfile-01.txt...smallfile-99.txt and output will be file_smallfile-00.txt  file_smallfile-01.txt... file_smallfile-99.txt

Comment: ok but still NOT clear on what basis you want to read the files? what is the criteria to get the output from files? Please explain.

Comment: I just wants to run this command on 99 files awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline<"Input the 1 to 99 files")>0) {REC[$2]=$0}} {print REC[$2]} <   file2 > output the 1 to 99 file with prefix name as "file 3_1 to file3_99"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `join` instead of `awk`:

```
join -1 1 -1 2 -2 1 -2 2 -o "1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 2.4"  smallfile bigfile
```

output:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A 4 C G
A 6 T A
```

pipe to `column -t`, if you want the output to match your expected spacing. 
(Note: `join` seems linear with regards to the number of lines in the files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441369/unix-join-command-complexity)